# Module 'KissXML' not found Error in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xmppframework

I am beginner in IOS development want to make chat app using XMPPFramework .
while integrating this library i had got this Error,I am attaching the image of error can any one help me regarding this.[image]

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods? Is `KissXML`  integrated into your project?

Comment: How did you add `XMPPFramework`? With CocoaPods? Or manually? If manually, did you do the step 4: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just replace your current pod with below one. it will fix your problem.

pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

Comment: yes ,I had added this                            platform :ios, ‘8.0’
   use_frameworks!

   target ‘XMPP’ do
pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

   end                             but getting error at console while pod install

Comment: [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `KissXML (~> 5.1.2)` required by `XMPPFramework/Core (3.7.0)`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `KissXML (~> 5.1.2)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

Comment: This is the hole Matter : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501121/trying-to-install-xmppframework-in-my-objective-c-project-using-podfile/41501385#41501385

Comment: try this pod first "pod setup" it will take time around 30min, you can check status into "Activity monitor" in your mac, once done then you can properly install your pod file.

Comment: Thanks @Bucket but but after open the project it give error while building this is the error message: Redefinition of mudule 'dnssd'

Comment: @premnath

Replace
"@import KissXML; with #import "KissXML.h"
"@import CocoaAsyncSocket; with #import "GCDAsyncSocket.h
in XMPPFramework header files.

Answer (score 0):

Adding
use_frameworks!
pod 'KissXML'
in Podfile solved my problem.