# Trying to install XMPPFramework in my objective c Project using Podfile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xmppframework

I am trying to install XMPPFramework in my objective c Project using Podfile.I had write this in my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

target ‘XMPP’ do
pod 'XMPPFramework', :git =>"https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

end
```

But I am getting this Error while `pod install`  this error is show in console.This is the image of console::

[image]

Can some one please Help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this in your pod file,**

> pod 'XMPPFramework'

**Remove ,**

> pod 'XMPPFramework', :git
>   =>"https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

**Run,**

> pod install

Try this. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @KAR it done successfully but after open the project it give error while building this is the error message: Redefinition of mudule 'dnssd'

Comment: @premnath how do resolved issue Redefinition of module dnssd ?