# Module 'KissXML' not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, xmppframework, kissxml

I read this and I try to solve it and didn't solved:
[Module 'KissXML' not found Error in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487744/module-kissxml-not-found-error-in-ios)

I setup my podfile like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'iPhoneXMPP' do
  pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.7.0'
end
```

Then in terminal I run:

```
pod install
```

It XMPPFramework will install "KissXML".
When I try to import it in my project it give me this error:

```
Module 'KissXML' not found
```

[pod file and error shown in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKI5r.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to input

## import "KissXML.h" insted of @import KissXML